# Prolog computing type of tuples

Tags: list, prolog

For an assignment, I have to create a type inference relation. here's the approach I used

```
tuples([]).
tuples(_|_).
type(tuples([]),tuples([])).
type(tuples(X|T),tuples(Y|Z)) :- type(tuples(T),tuples(Z)),type(X,Y).
```

I have already defined the type relation for all possible terms required for my assignment where y is the type of X in type(X,Y). For defining types of n-tuples, I used the approach similiar to the one used for appending lists.
But prolog always returns false when I ask

```
?-type(tuples([3,str]),Z)
```

or even

```
?-type(tuples([3,str]),tuples(Z))
```

or

```
?-type(tuples([3,str,4,abc,5,6]),Z)
```

i.e a list of length n, the answer returned is false.

Nothing changed even when I revered the sub-rules in the last rule.

```
tuples([]).
tuples(_|_).
type(tuples([]),tuples([])).
type(tuples(X|T),tuples(Y|Z)) :- type(X,Y),type(tuples(T),tuples(Z)).
```

I am not asking for alternative approaches to type of tuples to help me in my assignment but I can't figure out why this approach is not working.

Comment: `tuples(_|_).` is invalid syntax -regardless of the operator declarations. What kind of Prolog are you using? Maybe you meant `tuples([_|_])` instead.

Comment: GNU Prolog throws an error when you try to declare `tuples(_|_).` SWI Prolog is happy with it and changes it to, `tupes((_'|'_)).` (or equivalently `tuples('|'(_,_)).` Neither of which, as @false points out, is probably what you intended.

Comment: Oh my bad. that was the error. I guess I assumed the syntax to be like that having freshly programmed in ocaml. Thank you very much its working now.

Comment: @lurker: SWI is "happy" with a lot of invalid syntax.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your definition of a tuple is a List with length 2.

This rule does not check for that:

```
tuples(_|_).
```

What you probably want is this:

```
tuples([_,_]).
```

If you want it to check for any length list, use:

```
tuples([_|_]).
```

In the latter rule, the first wildcard represents the first item in the list (the head) and the second wildcard represents the rest of the list (the tail).

Comment: Actually, it is supposed to be a type checker for any n length tuple.
I should have mentioned that in the example too. I edited that now

Comment: @user3545354 this answer is on the right track, though. `_|_` doesn't represent a list. If you want a list, you need `[_|_]`.

Comment: oh yeah the error was in tuples(_|_). i replaced all such instances with ([_|_]). working fine now. thanks a lot